# Vuetify Slide Group Component left and right arrow should be shown on card over hover only

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify Slide Group Component, I want left and right to come up on card instead of occupying the extra space, I am trying to override the CSS. How we can do that?

```html
<v-slide-group show-arrows class="my-3 slide-group">
   <v-slide-group-item v-for="(item, index) in topPicks" :key="index" v-slot="{ toggle, selectedClass }">
            <AddToCart
              :item="item"
              :class="[selectedClass]"
              @click="toggle"
              @add-to-cart="store.action.addToCart(item.id)"
            />
  </v-slide-group-item>
 </v-slide-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a variable to control the display:

template:

```
<v-slide-group :show-arrows="show" @mouseenter="mouseenter" @mouseleave="mouseleave" class="my-3 slide-group">
```

js:

```
mouseenter () {
  show = true;
},

mouseleave () {
  show = false;
},
```